mongodb-community 7.0.12 on macOS Apple M3 Max: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
Upgraded (my working) mongodb-community 7.0.11 to 7.0.12
on macOS 14.5 Sonoma using:
brew upgrade 

& also tried:
brew uninstall mongodb-community
brew install mongodb-community

brew services restart mongodb-community

==> Successfully stopped `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community)
==> Successfully started `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community)

When I try to run 'mongosh' I get:
mongosh 
Current Mongosh Log ID: 667d256eae84701ef1dc2c4f
Connecting to:      mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+2.2.10
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:2701

Get similar error when I try to connect with 'MongoDB Compass' & 'Studio 3T':
mongodb://localhost:27017
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017, connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017

If I try to run mongod or mongos I get:
Illegal instruction: 4

Is there an issue of MongoDB on Apple M3 Max/ARM 64 ?
'Google'd' till the cows came home & can't find a fix! TIA.

Try use mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017 ? or check the mongod.conf net.bindIp setting

As I always start by: 'brew services restart mongodb-community'. Where would I add  the '0.0.0.0:27017'. Thanks.

connect with 'MongoDB Compass' & 'Studio 3T' by mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017 instead mongodb://localhost:27017

find your mongod.conf in /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf or /opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf and change the setting net.bindIp to ::,0.0.0.0 and restart the service.

or just use mongosh "mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/myDB"

Check if mongo is actually running. $ lsof -i :27017

Please show us your config file, typically /etc/mongod.conf and have a look at the logfile, usually /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

@user25009716 I don't think the problem comes from bindIp settings, because connection failed for 127.0.0.1 and ::1. With wrong bindIp it would not fail for both.

You write "appears to work on Studio 3T" but in your question you say "get similar error when I connect with Studio 3T". Please state properly what is working and what not.

@Wernfried Domscheit. Sorry it doesn't work either with MongoDB Compass or Studio 3T:
SERVER [0.0.0.0:27017] (Type: UNKNOWN)
|/ Connection error (MongoSocketOpenException): Exception opening socket
|___/ Socket error: Connection refused
Details:
Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=0.0.0.0:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]

Please edit your question for such information instead of a comment.

Illegal instruction means you have the wrong binary for your platform.

See my 'Answer' re upgrading to 'Apple Mac M3 Max/ARM 64 ". TIA.

Fixed - needs a 'macos-arm6' version of mongoDB Community:
Download & Unzipped: https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community
mongodb-macos-arm64-7.0.12-rc1.tgz

Copied (my preferance):
usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-macos-aarch64-7.0.12-rc1/
cd:
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-macos-aarch64-7.0.12-rc1/bin

Run:
./mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf

Add additional Terminal:
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-macos-aarch64-7.0.12-rc1/bin

Run:
mongosh

Terminal displays:
Current Mongosh Log ID: 667e9aa330e84e420487fce7
Connecting to:      mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+2.2.10
Using MongoDB:      7.0.12-rc1
Using Mongosh:      2.2.10

For mongosh info see: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/

------
   The server generated these startup warnings when booting
   2024-06-28T12:11:16.630+01:00: Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted
   2024-06-28T12:11:16.630+01:00: Soft rlimits for open file descriptors too low
------

Warning: Found ~/.mongorc.js, but not ~/.mongoshrc.js. ~/.mongorc.js will not be loaded.
  You may want to copy or rename ~/.mongorc.js to ~/.mongoshrc.js.
test> db = connect("127.0.0.1:27017/beWhereWhenDB");
beWhereWhenDB
beWhereWhenDB> 

beWhereWhenDB> // Users

beWhereWhenDB> load('/Users/NOTiFY/IdeaProjects/BeWhereWhen/js/beWhereWhen/Users.js')
>>>>> 1.1 dbName = beWhereWhenDB
>>>>> 1.2 dbName = beWhereWhenDB
>>>>> 1.3 collectionUsers deleteMany = [object Object]
>>>>> 1.4 collectionUsers = [object Object]
true
beWhereWhenDB> 

beWhereWhenDB> // Events, Meetings, Social

beWhereWhenDB> load('/Users/NOTiFY/IdeaProjects/BeWhereWhen/js/bewherewhen/EventsMeetingsSocial.js')
>>>>> 3.1 dbName = beWhereWhenDB
>>>>> 2.2 dbName = beWhereWhenDB
>>>>> 2.3 collectionEventsMeetingsSocial deleteMany = [object Object]
>>>>> 2.4 collectionEventsMeetingsSocial = [object Object]
true
beWhereWhenDB> 

beWhereWhenDB> 

beWhereWhenDB> // Events

beWhereWhenDB> load('/Users/NOTiFY/IdeaProjects/BeWhereWhen/js/beWhereWhen/BeWhereWhen.js')
>>>>> 3.1 dbName = beWhereWhenDB
>>>>> 3.2 dbName = beWhereWhenDB
>>>>> 3.3 collectionBeWhereWhen deleteMany = [object Object]
>>>>> 3.4 collectionBeWhereWhen = [object Object]
true
beWhereWhenDB> load('/Users/NOTiFY/IdeaProjects/BeWhereWhen/js/beWhereWhen/BeWhereWhen_Events.js')
>>>>> 4.1 collectionBeWhereWhen events = [object Object]
true


'Homebrew' needs ability to 'update/upgrade' automatically with 'brew':
mongodb/brew/mongodb-community 7.0.12

for:
Apple Mac M3 Max/ARM 64 

brew list  mongodb-macos-aarch64-7.0.12-rc1
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-macos-aarch64-7.0.12-rc1/bin/install_compass
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-macos-aarch64-7.0.12-rc1/bin/mongod
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-macos-aarch64-7.0.12-rc1/bin/mongos

